# importing pyjnius in python shell gives KeyError

Tags: python, pyjnius

I have installed pyjnius module in python 2.7.12. I don't really remember how did I installed it.

I have a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from jnius import autoclass

# do something here
```

I can run this without getting any error but when I try to write my code in the python shell, it gives an error.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from jnius import autoclass
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jnius/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from .reflect import *  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jnius/reflect.py", line 14, in <module>
class Class(with_metaclass(MetaJavaClass, JavaClass)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/six.py", line 827, in __new__
return meta(name, bases, d)
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 43, in jnius.MetaJavaClass.__new__ (jnius/jnius.c:18031)
File "jnius/jnius_export_class.pxi", line 65, in jnius.MetaJavaClass.resolve_class (jnius/jnius.c:18439)
File "jnius/jnius_env.pxi", line 11, in jnius.get_jnienv (jnius/jnius.c:3710)
File "jnius/jnius_jvm_dlopen.pxi", line 90, in jnius.get_platform_jnienv (jnius/jnius.c:3641)
File "jnius/jnius_jvm_dlopen.pxi", line 45, in jnius.create_jnienv (jnius/jnius.c:2965)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'JAVA_HOME'
```

Is there something wrong with my pyjnius?

I tried to uninstall my current pyjnius module using:

```
sudo apt-get purge pyjnius
```

But it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyjnius
```

I would appreciate any hints to my problem.

Comment: Do you have JAVA_HOME set as a system variable?

Comment: I don't think I've set JAVA_HOME as a system variable. I'll try it.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Alex Hristov, it worked. I tried to do the same thing as suggested in https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius/issues/209.